# Jenkins and IBM Udeploy connection issue 503 error

Tags: jenkins, urbancode, udeploy

Hi iam trying to integrate jenkins with Udeploy server.

When i test the connection using IBM UrbanCode Deploy Pipeline Plugin Configuration and the test connection option iam getting the below error

Error connecting to IBM UrbanCode Deploy: 503using URI: https://udeploy.oe.company/rest/state

I could confirm there is no issue with firewall. i am able to do a curl successfully to the url.

Iam not able to see anything in jenkins logs.
https://jenkinsurl.org/log/all

is there anyway i could check the logs of the plugin to see what is happening during connection?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an SSL issue. If using self-signed certs, try swapping the self signed certs. Note that Urbancode might be using the IBM JDK which has its own truststore, and you'll need to store the Jenkins certs there.